# Setting up new iPhone Dev Environment for existing app

Tags: iphone

This might be a weird question, but I'll try anyway.

I set up my dev environment with certificates etc on an old MBP, built an app and released it on the App Store. I've since upgraded to a new MacBook Pro, but didn't move over any certificates, so can no longer build my application.

Have I completely screwed things up? How can I install the right certificates on my new MBP? Note: I do not own the old MBP any longer so cannot transfer anything from there...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can allways download developer-certificates / provisioniong profiles from the [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action)

I hope that helps.

sam

Comment: When I originally setup my certs, I had to generate one from the MBP itself, upload to the portal, which in turn created the certs to install via xcode. That seems to be my issue - when I download certs from the portal they wont install ?

Comment: why not create a new one? https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

Comment: Certificates downloaded from the portal don't include the private key, they are the public part only. Downloading from the portal isn't the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thats correct, but do you see another way than creating a completely new one if the private part has gone due to a new macbook?

Comment: No - samsam you are right. A new certificate needs to be created.

Comment: Thanks guys - you are correct, I was missing the private part, so had to start over. This fixed the issues.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are running at least Xcode 3.2.2 (it may be present in earlier versions, too), on your old machine go to the Window menu and select Organizer. Then go to the Developer Profile section under iPhone Development. Select Export Developer Profile.

Copy it over to your new mac, go through the same steps to import and you should be good to go.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see you that you don't have your old machine. Will leave this here in case it's useful to someone else in the future.